# Can all USB 3.0 ports on tablets receive video (1080p @ 60fps)?

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, tablet, capture

I want to use my tablet as a monitor for my Raspberry Pi 4. To do this I'm using a AverMedia HDMI to USB C capture card. My old tablet won't accept the video-in signal because it's USB 2.0 (Galaxy Tab A7 Lite). It does work on my laptop with a USB 3.0 port. Will a new tablet with USB 3.0 like the Galaxy Tab S7 work?

**What I mean is: Is there a distinction between USB 3.0 capable ports and USB 3.0 video in capable ports?**

This reddit comment led me to believe there's a distinction: https://www.reddit.com/r/samsunggalaxy/comments/wvwn4m/comment/ilj7rd7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

I'm scared to blow 400 euros on a tablet to discover that I need more than just a normal USB 3.0 port.

Answer (score 0):

USB will have a constant latency. It will not go up from that. If your Video is not very high resolute then it will work. Otherwise you might see some glitch.